# What is the name of this connector?

Tags: connector, wire

A rectifier I salvaged from a broken oasta machine uses am odd plastic barrel connector. On the rectifier end, it looks like a banana pin housed in a translucent white plastic barrel. On the cable end, it looks like a tube. The diameters of the terminals are smaller than a standard banana connector.  Both terminals snap together on two ridges.

What is the name of this connector?

[image: Male connector pins]
[image: Male donnector body]

[image: Female connector mate]

[image: Femalw donnector body]

Comment: Looks like a bullet connector to me.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that, but haven't seen this one.

Comment: A regular bullet connector doesn't fir.  This one has a smaller diameter and locks in using the tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called a custom connector.

common  Shell, and Pin Socket Contact for each side.

One of [***these pins***](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-contacts/331?k=molex&k=&pkeyword=molex&pv78=134&pv78=190&pv78=58&pv78=4&pv78=135&FV=7c0039%2C3a40001%2C3a40002%2C1f140000%2Cffe0014b&mnonly=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=250) may fit your dimensions when you find the single wire interlock shell

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I found it.  It is made by Molex part # 1625-1PRT.  It is hideously expensive $16 for 1 at amazon. I guess I will use standard terminal connectors.  Kinda sucks because they are really cool and keeps things tidy.